# Longest increasing subsequence with binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, stack, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement some algorithm in python and I need help.
Given some array of integers,
I want to build BTS and find the Longest increasing subsequence.
The idea is to give index to each node(by order of inserting)
Next we want to take all the indices from the left tree and put them in stack
Next we want to check for each index in the above stack if we have in the tree index that is bigger than the current node, if yes we insert it to stack and update the value max which is the number of elements in our stack.

I need help at the point of scanning the tree and insert the elements into a stack.

here is my code so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, index = -1):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.key = key
        self.index = index

    def __str__(self):
        return "key: %s, index: %s" % (str(self.key), str(self.index))  

def insert(root, key, value=-1):
    if root is None:
        root = Node(key, value)
    else:
        if key < root.key:
            root.left = insert(root.left, key, value)
        elif key > root.key:
            root.right = insert(root.right, key, value)
        else:
            pass
    return root

def LeftSideIndices(root):
    res = []
    if root:
        res = LeftSideIndices(root.left)
        res.append(root.index)
    return res

def InOrderWithInsert(root,A):
    newStack = []

    if root:
        for i in range(0, len(A)):
            newStack = upInOrder(root.left,A)
            if root.index > A[i]:
                newStack.append(root.key)
            newStack = newStack + upInOrder(root.right, A)
    return newStack
```

Example:

[image]

**The right stack should be: s=[0,2,8,11]**

Comment: You have said what you want to do, but not what you need help with.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this with a binary search tree? Building a BST will be at least linear, and so too will just be scanning the list once to find the longest sequence without building a BST.

Comment: I updated what I need help with. 

And the reason that I want to do this, is that I saw this problem in some exercises at my university in the "Data Structures" course, I found a solution only in Pseudo Code and I want to implement it, if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some general remarks :

- providing a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is appreciated.
- your code does not define `upInOrder` so we can't run part of it
- nitpick: in the `insert` function your `value` parameter is passed to the `index` parameter of your `Node` constructor, the naming is confusing.
- reformulating your question to make it explicit : "given a Binary Search Tree, find the Longest Increasing Subsequence"
- there is a bug in your `LeftSideIndices` : it returns only indices of left (grand)children instead of the indices of the whole left-half of the tree, example :

  ```py
  bst = insert(insert(insert(None, 2, 0), 0, 1), 1, 2)
  #            val=2,idx=0
  #            /
  #  val=0,idx=1
  #            \
  #         val=1,idx=2
  print(LeftSideIndices(bst))  # [1, 0]
  ```
- for reference :

  ```py
  print("value | " + " | ".join(str(value).ljust(2) for value in A) + " |")
  print("index | " + " | ".join(str(index).ljust(2) for index in range(len(A))) + " |")
  # | value | 4  | 1  | 13 | 7  | 0  | 2  | 8  | 11 | 3  |
  # | index | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
  ```
- as said in the comments, another solution would be to not use a BST at all, and just search the LIS in `A` (which uses a much more common algorithm). I would even say that using a BST makes it pointlessly hard because the result has nothing to do with the BST structure, it is strictly defined by the insertion order, irregarding the datastructure considered.
- There may be multiple different subsequences having the same length (being the longest possible), example :

  ```py
  bst = insert(insert(insert(insert(None, 1, 0), 22, 1), 14, 2), 15, 3)
  #     val=1,idx=0
  #               \
  #               val=22,idx=1
  #               /
  #       val=14,idx=2
  #               \
  #            val=15,idx=3

  # Expected LIS = { (1, 22),   (14, 15) }
  ```

I read several times your algorithm explanation (slightly reformatted) :

> - take all the indices from the left tree and put them in stack
> - check for each index in the stack if we have in the tree index that is bigger than the current node
>
>   - if yes, insert it to stack and update the value max which is the number of elements in the stack.

I am not sure to understand your algorithm, and I don't think it works.

I am even not sure there is a simple solution to this problem.
The way your indices are scattered accross your tree prevent a node to know which solution(s) from its left and/or right sub-trees are interesting because there is too much holes in the index sequence in a sub-tree, the information at the node level is too much gappy.

Usually for trees algorithms, it is simple to apply some [divide and conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm), but in this case I can't even tell how recursively the root node could tell which is the longest subsequence, given the results of its left and righ subtrees.

But in your case it looks to me extra hard to find how to implement what you want. And I can't convince myself there is actually an algorithm. So I hope you will be able to prove me wrong.